# How to enable hover on a div for IE6 using jquery in minmal code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml

I just want to implement hover on a single div(for IE 6). what is the simplest , lightest, solution in jquery?

```
<div class="hoverforie">

</div>
```

i will add this script in IE condition comment.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Use [**hover**](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/hover) event

```
$(".hoverforie").hover(
      function () {
        // do your code for mouse over
      }, 
      function () {
        // do your code for mouse out
      }
    );
```

Comment: @rahul can you show an example how to use this can i use and id class or group selector

Comment: You can use any selector for this.

Answer (score 0):

And if you just want to apply it specifically for IE6... (although I think the methods are deprecated)

```
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version=="6.0")
{
    ...apply the hover function from @adamantium
}
```