# IE6 Hover Issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

The CSS `:hover` doesn't work in IE6 for elements that are not links. Is there a workaround? e.g. how do I apply the `:hover` to a `div`?

Comment: similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900768/how-to-enable-hover-on-a-div-for-ie6-using-jquery-in-minmal-code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's [whatever:hover](http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html). I've never used it myself but from what I hear, it works well.

> Whatever:hover is a small script that automatically patches :hover, :active and :focus for IE6, IE7 and IE8 quirks, letting you use them like you would in any other browser. Version 3 introduces ajax support, meaning that any html that gets inserted into the document via javascript will also trigger :hover, :active and :focus styles in IE.

Comment: isn't there a css alternative for that?

Comment: @Sarfraz as far as I know, no, otherwise whatever:hover and other workarounds wouldn't exist.

Comment: +1, my thoughts as soon as I'd read the title.  whatever:hover traverses the stylesheets converting pseudo classes to class names and attaching the required event handlers.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the famous [IE7.js](http://dean.edwards.name/IE7/) from Dean Edwards, which has the nice advantage, that you can use the `:hover` selector in your CSS.

Apart from that, I doubt that you can achieve it with CSS alone. IE can handle JS in CSS files via `expression()`, but you can't get to an expression to handle hovering without a selector handling hovering, if you catch my drift.

Then, finally, a short jQuery solution:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('div').hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass('hover');
  }, function () {
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
  });
});
```

Then you can use this in your stylesheet:

```
div:hover, div.hover { ... }
```

Comment: +1 for this one too.  Overkill for `:hover` support alone, but great if you wanted all the extra stuff and just didn't know it yet.

Comment: @Andy E: True, that it is overkill for `:hover` alone. Actually, mostly when an answer starts with 'You can use jQuery or this...' this is exactly what I comment then. ;-) However, like you mention, dealing with IE6 I often find myself thinking of IE7.js in a bunch of different situations.

Answer (score 3):

- If you only need for paticulars div
  and you are not using jquery then go
  for suckerfis js as @futta
  suggested.http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/
- If you are planning to use Hover on more tags in future and don't want to edit every time js for this the go for **Whatever.htc** in  for IE6. as @Pekka suggested.

> ```
> Suckerfish vs. .htc
> ```
>
> IIIIN the blue corner we have
>   Suckerfish, the original lightweight,
>   accessible, cross-browser,
>   standards-compliant :hover mimic.
>   IIIIN the red corner we have '.htc' -
>   the JavaScript files accessed via CSS
>   to mimic :hover.
>
> Ding ding!
>
> And Suckerfish instantly lands a heavy
>   blow on .htc's validity - .htc simply
>   isn't standards compliant CSS.
>
> Oooo... .htc sneaks in a crafty jab
>   without the need for additional
>   selectors...
>
> Suckerfish bounces around the ring.
>   He's much lighter weight than his
>   opponent.
>
> And OH! The IE 5.0 uppercut! That's
>   something that .htc just doesn't have
>   the skill to do, whereas Suckerfish
>   can work IE 5.0 seamlessly.
>
> .htc is dazed! And the contest is
>   over! Suckerfish wins on points! TKO!

- IF you want to get benefit for other things (other than Hover) also in
  **IE** then go for `IE7.js` as @Boldewyn suggested
- And If you are already using jquery
  and want to use hover in a limited
  way then go for This way :
  [How to enable hover on a div for IE6 using jquery in minmal code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900768/how-to-enable-hover-on-a-div-for-ie6-using-jquery-in-minmal-code)

**NO pure and valid CSS solution available for this in IE6.**

- One **Non- valid CSS expression solution** is available
  but i would not not advise to use
  this [because it's slow](http://blog.dynatrace.com/2010/02/16/the-real-performance-overhead-of-css-expressions/)

  Solution: http://www.visibilityinherit.com/code/ie6-hover-expression.php

Comment: For my requirement, suckerfish solution should suffice.

Answer (score 2):

[suckerfish and it's offspring](http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/) provde great lightweight alternatives for this purpose too.