# Hover submenu in IE6

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-6

I am developing web with wordpress and have a problem with it's submenu. The problem is that it doesn't appear with hover on IE6. There must be something wrong with css, i guess. Any ideas? Is this possible to be done without javascript?

as i understand the problem is with #access ul ul { display:none; } as i delete it, it shows allways the submenu.. is there ny way to change it into something?

Comment: Not PHP related and as a hint google suckerfish-dropdowns.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE6 Hover Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571073/ie6-hover-issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope it is not possible without javascript at least in IE6, you need javascript for IE6 :(

Here are some options for you:

[IE6 Hover Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571073/ie6-hover-issue)

Comment: Does it add :hover support on all elements? Judging by the documentation, all CSS3Pie can do is add certain CSS3 specific declarations, which :hover isn't.

Comment: @Gordon: I am not sure for that but here are some other options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571073/ie6-hover-issue

Comment: Well, I know there is other options :) Just doubting CSS3Pie as a solution. On a sidenote, when you asked the same question yourself once, why no closevote on this one?

Answer (score 2):

My guess since I don't have the code is that the submenu is using li:hover to cause the submenu to appear.  IE6 only supports the :hover pseudoclass on <a> tags (only a:hover will work in IE6).

Check out [CSS Play](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/final_drop.html) for some CSS only dropdown menu examples.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible with this simple trick (**overflow-height-trick**).

***Note that:***

1. A container should have real height.
2. A wrapper should have real height and "position:absolute".
3. A childs of wrapper should have real height and "position:relative".

Wrap your menu like this:

```
< div id="container" >

 < div id="menu_wrapper >
  < div id="selector" >Computed Value< / div >
  < ul id="menu" >
   < li >Predefined Value< / li >
   < li >Predefined Value< / li >
   < li >Predefined Value< / li >
  < ul >
 < / div >

< / div >
```

Set styles:

```
< style >
div#container{height:100%;}
div#menu_wrapper{height:32px; position:absolute;}
div#menu_wrapper:hover{height:100%;}
div#selector{height:32px;clear:both;}
ul#menu li{height:32px;}
< / style >
```

Enjoy )