# CSS LI hover - browser compatible?

Tags: css, hover, html-lists

NOOB question...

Does `LI:HOVER{background:url(image.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;}` work across all browsers?

Comment: Well the `:hover` pseudo selector does not work in IE6, works only for links.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE6 Hover Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571073/ie6-hover-issue)

Answer (score 6):

[IE versions older than 7 won't support it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024(VS.85).aspx).

I recommend [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage).

Also, [background-repeat is supposed to be defined before background-position](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_background.asp), although most browsers will understand the values in whichever order they are given.

Comment: Just to add a note to the answer: `:hover` has problems with touch screens, so the answer to OP's question would be "no" for those browsers, unless we take in place come tricks and workarounds. But I'm sure it would be better to have a different behaviour in those cases, instead of the `:hover` pseudo class.

Answer (score 5):

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html , yes, but <= IE6 has some problems, but who cares?

Comment: if by "some problems" you mean that it isn't working at all, i agree. `:hover` only works for links in IE6, and OP's question is with regards to `LI`.

Comment: + one for that ;) But still, who cares about <IE7 ? Even Microsoft doesn't want it anymore

Comment: Is there a way to battle the "flicker" between loading image?  when i mouse off, i get the white flicker...