# CSS - using :hover on elements other than links

Tags: html, css, hover, css-selectors, opera

For ages now my site has had a catalogue where the small image is directly within a link within a div. The link must only be around the image - but I do not want to use the + selector since this is not supported by some versions of IE (IE6 onwards I think it needs to support). The div has class "ImageHoverSpan" (it used to be a Span on an older layout, I just havent bothered renaming the class). There is another div, with class "ImageOuterPanel", on the same level as the link (i.e. a direct child of the ImageHoverSpan).

I have the following classes defined:

```
  .ImageHoverSpan .ImageOuterPanel {
    display: none; }
  .customer .ImageHoverSpan:hover .ImageOuterPanel {
    display: block; }
```

This certainly used to work fine as far as I can remember - on all browsers. I am about to launch the new version of the website into testing, but I just noticed today that, in Opera 10.60, the image panel (ImageOuterPanel) is displaying straight away on hover over the ImageHoverSpan, but it takes anything between 1 second and.. well.. never to disappear when the mouse leaves the div.

I know using :hover on anything other than links can slow performance in IE - but this is Opera. In Firefox (3.6) this works absolutely fine - it appears and disappears as it should.

Has anyone got any ideas about what could be causing this? Anyone had this problem before?

Thank you.

Regards,

Richard

Comment: Why are you worrying about IE *before* 6? I mean it's bad enough having to cater for IE6 but before then?

Comment: I am not - "(IE6 onwards I think it needs to support)"

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE6 Hover Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571073/ie6-hover-issue)

Comment: @Sarfraz - Its not a duplicate of IE6 Hover Issue - this is Opera 10.60, as I said above. Its a different issue altogether.

Comment: @ClarkeBoy your sentence reads `but I do not want to use the + selector since this is not supported by some versions of IE (IE6 onwards I think it needs to support)` yes IE6 onwards = IE6 and onwards, so you're worrying about things before IE6. Did you mean it needs IE *later* than 6 rather than including 6?

Comment: I mean IE6 and onwards. To be honest its getting so far on from 6 (as in they are making IE9 right now) that I may ask the company to just forget about 6. Other than that it needs to work on IE7 and 8, FF 2 and 3.* and Opera 9 - 10 (I believe Opera forces users to upgrade after so long, so dont think there is any need to support prior to 9). Besides Opera only has 2.3% of the market according to W3.

Right now this bug seems to only appear on Opera 10.60 - I am about to test Chrome and IE though.

Comment: Ok now I know its just an Opera issue. I am going to totally forget about IE6 since, based on what the page looks like, it hasnt been tested in IE6 in a long long time. It works great in IE7, 8, FF3.6 and Chrome (the latest version - whatever that is).

Its just one of those annoying little glitches - the type you tend to expect to see in IE.. seems in this case IE has exceeded my expectations. I bet its only a typo or something as small as that which is causing this issue too.

Comment: Ok I have spoken to the company and they really dont care about this glitch - Opera only has 2.3% usage according to W3 and its not as if the enlargements dont show - its that they take their time to disappear. It would be a bit more of a problem if they didnt appear at all. They have said to just go ahead and put it into testing anyway. As for IE6 - well who cares about IE generally anyway??

Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have found an answer. I asked the question on the Opera forums, and a user posted back that I could have an Opera stylesheet which keeps the elements visible but sets opacity to 0 or 100 instead. This works - the elements appear and disappear instantly.

Richard