# Navigation dropdown not working in ie6?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

Im trying to get my navigation working in IE6 with no luck, the sub navigation is positioned absolutely -9999px and on hover comes into display, or should.

I've made a fiddle to see if anyone can work it out, Any helps is greatly appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/Fz9BX/

Comment: i don't think ie6 supports :hover on other elements than a...

Comment: http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/csshover.html - from the accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2571073/681807

Comment: Stop supporting an 11 year old browser?

Comment: Even though this has completely nothing to do with HTML5 (I've removed the tag), if you're trying to build with HTML5 then it's not realistic to expect IE6 compatibility.

Comment: I would just stop supporting IE6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use javascript for IE6 to work. On your parent level `<li>`, just add a listener and add/remove a hover class.

Then add to your css the rule for `li.hover` as well as `li:hover`