# Cross Browser Issues With Positioning HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I am stuck in cross-browser compatibility hell and I just do not have the web design expertise (I am a web developer) to figure out how to fix the issue without breaking it on other browsers. I would appreciate any advice for changing the html and css to make it compatible between browsers (IE9, Firefox, Chrome). I am also having the issue where the hover over the anchor link ("Buy it!") is moving components around due to the text resize. I tried to compensate by changing the padding on hover events to no avail. Thank you for any advice you can give somebody who is more used to java/php coding than html/css.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">

            body
            {
                background: #EEEEEE;
            }

            div#demo
            {
                background: #5B9EE0;
                margin-left:auto;
                margin-right:auto;
                width:650px;
                font-family: verdana, normal, sans-serif;
                border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;             
            }

            div#demoHeader
            {
                text-align:center;
                font-size:24px;
                font-weight:bold;
                color:#FFFFFF;
            }

            div#demoFooter
            {
                clear:both; 
                padding:5px;    
                font-size:28px;
                background-color:#EEEEEE;
                text-align:right;
            }

            form#demoForm #demoBodyText
            {
                float:left;
                margin-left:10px;
                padding:6px;
            }

            form#demoForm #demoBodyOptions
            {
                float:left;
                margin-right:10px;
                width:300px;
            }

            form#demoForm fieldset
            {
                margin: 0; 
                padding: 0; 
                border: none;
            }

            form#demoForm fieldset legend
            {
                font-size:16px;
                font-weight: bold;
                color:#FFF;
            }

            fieldset#demoBodyText #demoBodyTextArea
            {
                width:300px;
                height:200px;
                border-color: #DAE9F8;
                border-style: solid;
                border-width: 4 px;
                -moz-border-radius: 5px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
                border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; 
                padding:4px;
                resize:none;
            }

            .demoOptionsLabelCell
            {
                width:70px;
                text-align:left;
                display:inline;
                float:left;
            }

            .demoOptionsSelectCell
            {
                width:110px;
                display:inline;
                float:left; 
            }

            .demoOptionsSelectCell select
            {
                /*float:right;*/
            }

            #demoBodyOptions .demoOptionsRow
            {
                background: #85B5E7;
                border-color: #DAE9F8;
                border-style: solid;
                border-width: 2px;
                -moz-border-radius: 5px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
                border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
                height: 20px;
                list-style: none;
                padding:5px;
                margin-bottom: 2px;
            }

            #demoBodyOptions .demoOptionsRowItems
            {
                list-style-type: none;
                display: inline;
            }

            #demoBodyOption .demoOptionsRowItems li
            {
                display: inline;
            }

            #demoSubmitListItem
            {
                line-height:20px;
            }

            #demoSubmitButton
            {
                border: none;
                width:108px;
                height:30px;
                font-size:20px;

                -moz-border-radius: 20px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
                -khtml-border-radius: 20px;
                border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
                color: #000;
                background-color:FF9900;
                position:relative;
                left:34px;
                bottom:2px;
                clear:both;
            }

            #demoSubmitButton:hover
            {
                font-weight: bold;
                cursor:pointer;
                cursor:hand;
            }

            a#demoLink
            {
                border: none;
                padding-left:20px;
                padding-right:20px;
                padding-top:3px;
                text-decoration:none;
                padding-bottom:4px;
                font-size:20px;
                -moz-border-radius: 20px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
                -khtml-border-radius: 20px;
                border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
                color: #000;
                background-color:FF9900;
                position:relative;
                left:5px;
                bottom:2px;
            }

            #demoLink:hover
            {
                font-weight:bold;
                padding-right:16px;
                padding-left:16px;
                text-decoration:none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="demo">
            <div id="demoHeader">
                Demo
            </div>
            <div id="demoBody">
                <form id = "demoForm" name="demoForm" method="get" action="myscript.php">
                    <fieldset id="demoBodyText">
                        <legend align="center">Demo Text</legend>
                        <textarea id="demoBodyTextArea"  onFocus="if(this.value == 'Enter your demo text here!'){this.value=''; this.onFocus=null;}">Enter your blah blah here!</textarea>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset id="demoBodyOptions">
                        <legend align="center"  >Options</legend>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="demoOptionsRow">
                                <ul class="demoOptionsRowItems">
                                    <li class="demoOptionsLabelCell">
                                        Option:
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="demoOptionsSelectCell">
                                        <select>
                                            <option class="center" value="divider">----(US English)----</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="demoOptionsRow">
                                <ul class="demoOptionsRowItems">
                                    <li class="demoOptionsLabelCell">
                                        Option:
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="demoOptionsSelectCell">
                                        <select>
                                            <option value="320">Fastest</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="demoOptionsRow">
                                <ul class="demoOptionsRowItems">
                                    <li class="demoOptionsLabelCell">
                                        Option:
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="demoOptionsSelectCell">
                                        <select>
                                            <option value="4.2">Highest</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="demoOptionsRow">
                                <ul class="demoOptionsRowItems">
                                    <li class="demoOptionsLabelCell">
                                        Option:
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="demoOptionsSelectCell">
                                        <select>
                                            <option value="none">None</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li style="list-style:none;">
                                <a href="http://www.google.com" id="demoLink">Buy it!</a>
                                <input id = "demoSubmitButton" type="submit" value="Do it!" />
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="demoFooter">
                Powered by <img align="top" src="someimage" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <br/>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

At Sparky672's insistence here is the breakdown of what exactly is going on. The position of the two buttons is not consistent across browsers. In Mozilla they line up on the bottom, in chrome the right button is a little further down, and in ie everything is completely aligned differently. This is therefore not fixable by changing the relative positions of the buttons as any change to fix on browser results in inconsistent positioning in the others (ie fix ie, chrome and firefox misalign buttons).

EDIT 2:

*In terms of what I expect it look like, the two buttons to be aligned with the bottom of the options rows in all three browsers.*

Thanks again for your suggestions, I am trying them out as quickly as I can.

JSFiddle Location:

http://jsfiddle.net/73Vs3/

Comment: Please clarify the wording of this.  You talk about a cross-browser issue without saying what it is.  Then you said you **also** have a hover issue... is that the same issue or another one?

Comment: The issue is the placement of the anchor link (Buy it!) and the button (Do it!). The anchor link hover issue is separate, but I figured somebody who read the question might know a quick solution. The Java/PHP is just me letting everyone know that my experience is in actual programming, not web design so people know a little bit about my background so they know the level we can discuss the issue at hand. Apologies for the lack of clarity.

Comment: Please _edit the question_ to explain the exact issue using descriptive words.  You have to tell us what you mean by _"placement"_... too far down, right, left, not aligned vertically, horizontally, what?  Don't assume we'd agree on what looks correct and pretend like **we don't know a single thing about what you've envisioned.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the special padding for `a#demoLink:hover`, and to `a#demoLink` add:

```
display: block;
float: left;
white-space: nowrap;
width: 72px; /*This should be the width, in pixels, that you want the button to remain*/
```

This effectively cancels the effect that the size of the child text has on the parent container. (see: http://jsfiddle.net/5yVzV/)

EDIT: also, to `#demoSubmitButton`, remove `clear: both` and add:

```
display: block;
float: left;
```

Comment: Beautiful, that fixed the positioning discrepancies across firefox and Chrome. In IE it still looks a little strange, but its bearable. Do you know why in IE the Do it! button is not bolding and changing to the hand cursor on hover, nor the rounding of all the elements? I looked on w3 schools and there does not appear to be special syntax for IE for these features.

Comment: Make sure you specify a doctype before your opening `<html>` tag or IE will render the document in Quirks Mode, which will produce a bunch of wacky layout issues. Also, IE6 only recognizes the `:hover` pseudoclass for the `<a>` element unless you add a special script to your CSS. See this thread for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571073/ie6-hover-issue

Comment: When I use XHTML transitional, suddenly the background of the <a> tag for Buy it! dissapears, and the color of the Do it tag changes to white. What explains this behavior? Although it did fix the rest of the issues on IE, so thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For #demoLink, add this :

```
display: inline-block;
width:100px;
text-align: center;
```

and remove padding on the #demoLink:hover

```
a#demoLink:hover
{
  font-weight:bold;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

do the same thing for #demoSubmitButton

Comment: So that unfortunately still has the two "buttons" aligned differently in ie, firefox, and chrome. Should I do away with the relative positioning all together? I feel like the floating I am doing with the two fieldsets are causing the problems here. Would it be better to relatively position them, and do away with the floating?

Comment: @thatidiotguy, that's because you've yet to explain the issue in your question.  The person simply proposed a solution to the one and only issue you've mentioned... the hover issue.

Comment: I posted an edit explaining further the problem at hand. In terms of what I expect it look like, the two buttons to be aligned with the bottom of the options rows in all three browsers.

Comment: @thatidiotguy, thanks.  I also copied your last comment up into the question as it's the _only_ thing explaining what you desire to be the end result.  The quality of your answers directly depends on the quality of your question.

Comment: The hex color values for `background-color` on both elements are missing the preceding #, meaning they won't be recognized as a valid color and will be ignored.

Comment: how on earth did that comment get in this thread? It's been a long week.