# Hide on :hover, DIV over DIV

Tags: css, animation, html

I have a DIV on top of another DIV.

What I want to achieve is hide the DIV on top to be able to access the DIV below.

I've tried opacity, but since the top DIV is still there, just transparent, It won't allow me to interact with the content of the DIV below.
I've also tried display:none;, visibility: hidden; and z-index. None of those would work.

How do I achieve this with CSS3, so I can also use a transition?

**HTML:**

```
<li class="panel-box"> 
    <div class="front box-style"> </div>
    <div class="back"> </div> 
</div> </li>
```

**CSS:**

```
.panel-box {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    width: 310px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

.box-style {
    background-color: red;
}

.front {
    width: 310px;
    height: 200px;
    z-index: 5;
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.front:hover {
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;  
}

.back {
    width: 310px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: rgba(57, 54, 55, 0.95);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: no matter what, css alone won't offer a solution for older browsers, especially IE which until recently only accepted the pseudo-class `:hover` on `a` elements (links).

Comment: In that case, what would you recommend? I'm not really good with anything besides HTML and CSS, if you don't mind helping out?

Comment: [This](http://geek.ryanhellyer.net/2009/12/10/ie-hovers/) and [this](http://www.sidesofmarch.com/index.php/archive/2007/04/23/an-ie6-compatible-solution-for-hover/) are possibly adequate :hover compatibility solutions that you can look at

Comment: Also [this page](http://css-tricks.com/css-transparency-settings-for-all-broswers/) discusses transparency, IE and css and may have some information useful to you. I'm actually looking up div/opacity and I don't think there is going to be a solution in CSS that matches your criteria, at least not to my knowledge... the googling continues...

Comment: :hover compatibility also addressed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571073/ie6-hover-issue

Comment: At this point, I don't really care about IE. I just want to be able to access the content on the DIV below. I've tried using the flip transition, that worked but not on all browsers and the content below is sort of crucial. Is there anything I can do to expose this content, while hiding the top DIV? Thanks.

Comment: Instead of `.front:hover{display:none}` (which will make `.front` no longer `:hover` and cause problem), can you use `li.panel-box:hover > .front{display:none}`?

Comment: Hmmm - this is actually a problem I have faced before, and I actually usually end up using JQuery to remove the div completely after fade on hover - Have you tried messing with the z-index of the elements inside the back div?

Comment: The demo below solves my problem. Chrome doesn't handle the transitions as good, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put together a bit of a workaround that seems to do some of this, but it will likely fail miserably on IE.

Tested and works reasonably on Chrome… YMMV :)

It uses a combination of `z-index` and sibling selectors to allow the front/back divs to swap places in the stacking context.

I had to swap places with front/back to use the CSS sibling selectors.  I don't claim this is a perfect example, but perhaps it'll get the ideas flowing.

Basically what is happening here is:

- As the mouse enters - trigger `.front:hover`
- front z-index goes to -1 triggering `.back:hover`
- back z-index immediately goes to 100 keeping it on top of the stack
- sibling selector back:hover + front keeps the front opacity at 0
- When the mouse transitions out, this all reverses

The reverse transition is not very smooth - haven't quite figured out if that can be fixed yet.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/meFgw/1/)

**CSS**

```
.panel-box {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    width: 310px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

.front {
    width: 310px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: 5;
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease;
}

.front:hover {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

.back {
    width: 310px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(57, 54, 55, 0.95);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease;
}

.back:hover + .front {
    opacity: 0;
}

.back:hover {
    z-index: 100;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<li class="panel-box">
    <div class="back">content goes here</div>
    <div class="front box-style"></div>
</li>
```