# Javascript On hover

Tags: javascript, html, class

assume I have this sample code:

```
<div class="class1">
  ... random content
</div>
```

Now all I want to do is just have a Javascript for on hover of that div, I need to add a css attribute:

```
background-color:#ffffe0;
border:1px solid #bfbfbf;
```

Thats really all I wish to achieve, however I wish to do this without jQuery.

EDIT: I don't really need a CSS solution as my application runs in quirks mode, which means it is not compatible in IE.

Comment: Why not to use CSS `:hover` pseudo-class?

Comment: I already have, however my application doesnt support that for IE as it is old and running quirks mode. I need javascript support for multi browser compatibility

Comment: While I'm sure you will get a solution without any effort on your behalf, it is better to post [**your code/css/etc**](http://whathaveyoutried.com) you have tried and might have issues with so we can have a look and help to see why it doesn't work. Also, adding a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsFiddle.net) (or similar) that demonstrates any issues you might have is helpful too.

Comment: The duplicate is not correct. Should be closed for this one instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/608788/css-hover-vs-javascript-mouseover?rq=1

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev Yours is also not correct, as it does not provide a solution for pure JS.

Comment: Ok, I don't have the time right now to find the exact JS dupe for this question. Reopened. @VisioN do you? :|

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Or mabey instead of spending time trying to close my thread down, you could spend half that time and answer my question? would be appreciated.

Comment: @user3378366 ok I'll do my best, but I'm sure there's a dupe somewhere ;)

Comment: @FrançoisWahl That thread has no relation to javascript what so ever. Can i ask what is wrong with this community? your all trying so hard to get my thread closed down instead of helping me out. Really bad impression to me.

Comment: @user3378366: `Or mabey instead of spending time trying to close my thread down, you could spend half that time and answer my question?`....what have you tried so far --> [**http://whathaveyoutried.com**](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: @FrançoisWahl I have tried researching online to find and learn about this.

Comment: @user3378366: More research: [**ie6-hover-issue**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571073/ie6-hover-issue) - points to `whatever:hover` --> [**http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/csshover.html**](http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/csshover.html)

Comment: I edited. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps:

http://jsbin.com/podip/2/edit

```
// IE6 does not support getElementsByClassName so...

function getElementsByClassName(className) { // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584635/getelementsbyclassname-doesnt-work-in-ie6
  var elz = [];
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var names = elements[i].className.split(' ');
    for (var j = 0; j < names.length; j++) {
      if (names[j] == className) elz.push(elements[i]);
    }
  }
  return elz;
}

// I like to use this nice function of mine to play with styles:

function css( el, obj ){
  if(typeof obj == "object" ){
    for(var k in obj){
      el.style[k] = obj[k];
   }
  } // else, it's not an {} so you might want to handle 'string' here... 
}

var $cl1 = getElementsByClassName("class1"); // Let's use now our fn

function hoverEvents( element ){
  element.onmouseenter = function(){
    css( element, {
      backgroundColor: "#ffffe0",
      border : "1px solid #bfbfbf"
    });
  };
  element.onmouseleave = function(){
    css( element, {
      backgroundColor: "transparent",
      border : "none"
    });
  };
}

// Set hover states by passing the element to our hoverEvents fn

for(var i=0; i<$cl1.length; i++){
  hoverEvents( $cl1[i] ); // bound listeners to all our elements
}
```

Comment: Works, but on mouseleave, it stays with the same css attributes that you get on hover.

Comment: @user3378366 have you seen that I changed in my code `none` to `transparent` ? Please take a look again after my edit.